# Pointing CloudFront URL with different file names to same file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I've files stored in an AWS S3 in the following format

```
https://s3.amazon.com/0001/123465/cat.png
https://s3.amazon.com/0001/489887/dog.png
https://s3.amazon.com/account_id/unique_file_id/dog.png
```

There is also a CloundFront in front of it, so the URLS are like

```
https://df13d2as1fa1a3.cloudfront.net/0001/123465/cat.png
```

The file name "cat.png" is recorded in our own database. We'd like to allow our users to be able to rename files without affecting the existing URLS. So for example, when cat.png is renamed to cat_new.png, (File ID remains same)

```
https://df13d2as1fa1a3.cloudfront.net/0001/123465/cat.png
and
https://df13d2as1fa1a3.cloudfront.net/0001/123465/cat_new.png
```

should both work and point to the same file. Is there any way to get this work?

Before we moved to AWS, the file url points to a PHP script, and it will download the same content no matter what the last file name is. It only looks for the account id and file id in URL.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to copy the file to the new location. S3 supports Web Page Redirects but that won't work for you on a large scale, and the bucket probably isn't set up as a website bucket.

You'll have to have a "redirect" application that performs the DB lookup and returns a 301 to the actual file. Because the CDN caches responses, it shouldn't be hit too hard (especially if you set up a long TTL on the redirect response)